# iPad Screen Video Recording from within the iPad

Tags: ipad, video, video-capture

For support and debugging purposes, it would be great if one could record the screen of an iPad directly from the iPad itself.

The perfect scenario would be to open the recording app on the iPad, have it run in the background, open your app, go through some screens, close your app, then stop the recording app, and you should have a video of everything I just mentioned. Anything out there like that?

Thanks!

**Edit**: iPad should not have to be jail-broken.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### This is not possible on a non-jailbroken device.

However, if your device is jailbroken, I would highly recommend [Display Recorder](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/displayrecorder/) by Ryan Petrich. I use it quite a bit to record my applications to show features and upload the videos to Youtube. Not to mention I have used it a few times to record issues with my apps and share them with my team.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Jailbreaking the iPad is unfortunately not an option.

Comment: Then your only other option would be to mirror the display to an AppleTV and use some other external recording device. Beyond that, there is no way to record video from your iPad in the manner you want.

Comment: That is unfortunate. I see it as such a useful feature to have.